# Computing the fundamental group of 1-skeletons

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I'm aware of the idea of a CW complex and how to use the van Kampen, I'm struggling with the concept however of computing the fundamental group of the 1-skeleton of spaces. 
For example, let us consider the simple spaces of the torus $\mathbb{T}$ and the Klein bottle $\mathbb{K}$. The CW structures of these spaces consists of one 0-cell, two 1-cells and one 2-cell.

Hence we can determine the fundamental groups of these spaces simply by looking at the 1-skeleton, consisting of one 0-cell, two 1-cells and considering the attaching maps of the 2-cell $\varphi : S^1 \longrightarrow X$.

I'm unsure of what this attaching map is and how to proceed with the computation of the fundamental group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generators are given by the 1-cells, the relations by the 2-cells. In the torus, you can attach a 2-cell to a square with opposite sides identified. The boundary of the 2-cell traces the path $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$. So this is the relation imposed among the generators $a$ and $b$.

The Klein bottle is similar.

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot

Comment: How about attaching a $3$-cell to the $2$-cell to build a solid torus? Wouldn't this change the fundamental group of the complex to $\mathbb Z$? Is it possible the fundamental group doesn't change only when we attach the $3$-cell along a loop, i.e., along $1$-cells?

Comment: @TakenSpark The fundamental group is determined entirely by the 2-skeleton. Adding a 3-cell doesn't change the fundamental group at all.

Comment: So how can it be that the solid torus has fundamental group Z, while the torus has Z + Z? Well you can't get a solid torus from a torus by attaching a 3-cell. There is no continuous map from the boundary of a 3-cell to the torus which traverses a toroidal loop in the torus.

Comment: what you could do instead is have a 1-skeleton of the usual toroidal and poloidal two circles, attach _two_ 2-cells, one along the usual $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ path, and another along just $a$, so you have a torus with a single cross section. Now how have a space where you can attach a 3-cell nontrivially. This is analogous to the natural cell structure you get by viewing the solid torus as a solid cube with a single pair of opposite faces identified.

Comment: Note that the single cross section, the 2-cell along just $a$, is a nullhomotopy of one of the generators, so that tells you that the fundamental group is already $\mathbb{Z}$ already in the 2-skeleton. So as promised, the 3-cell does not change the fundamental group.

Comment: yes that is perfect, I actually put up a question about this example and I got this reply as well. I should have analyzed the attaching maps more carefully.

I have a question though, so I've written a sketch of why the attaching $3,4,\dots$-cells doesn't change the fundamental group of a CW complex, however, this proof seems to use only the continuity of the attaching map (implicitly) and the fact that $3,4,\dots$-spheres are simply connected. Could it be that if I allow a non-continuous attaching, the extension of fundamental group to these new objects would change the fundamental group?

Comment: @TakenSpark sure, if the attaching maps are not continuous, then all bets are off. For example you can maps a 2-sphere surjectively onto a 1-sphere if you allow discontinuous maps. I am a little nervous about making any declarations along the lines of "CW spaces with discontinuous attaching maps map have their homotopy killed by higher cells", because I'm not sure the topology of such a space is even well-defined, since discontinuous maps don't respect topologies. But I guess if you were careful you could make it work.